# Is $2^{\alpha} < 2^{\beta}$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are cardinal numbers, such that $\alpha < \beta$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be cardinal numbers such that $\alpha < \beta$. Isn't it always true that $2^{\alpha} < 2^{\beta}$ ? Because if I am not wrong, $2^{\alpha}$ denotes the immediate successor of $\alpha$ by GCH.
 Can anyone please suggest me some good book which can clarify my concepts on cardinals, ordinals and cofinality. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Already answered: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244870/why-continuum-function-isnt-strictly-increasing.

Comment: You could try 'Classic set Theory' by Derek Goldrei, although I don't know if it has exactly what you want.