# Power sets : Do the relations between P(A) and P(B) always mirror the relations between the sets A and B?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I am correct it is true that:

(1) "$P(A)$ is included in $P(B)$" implies "$A$ is included in $B$".

(2) "$P(A) = P(B)$" implies "$A = B$".

Might I conclude from this that the power sets of two sets always have the same relations as these two sets have with one another?

Are there **classical counterexamples** to this (hasty) generalization?

I can think of this as a counterexample :

The fact that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint does NOT imply that $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are disjoint.

---

Attenpt to prove (1) using the theorem : "$\{ x \}$ belongs to $P(S)$" $\Longleftrightarrow$ "$x$ belongs to $S$.

Let's admit that : $P(A)$ is included in $P(B)$.

Now, suppose (in view of refutation) that $A$ is not included in $B$.

It means that there exists an x such that x belongs to $A$ but not to $B$. And consequently that there is an $x$ such that $\{ x \}$ belongs to $P(A)$ but not to $P(B)$. If this were true, there would be a set $S$ such that $S$ belongs to $P(A)$ but not to $P(B)$. This contradicts our hypothesis according to which $P(A)$ is included in $P(B)$.

Conclusion: "$P(A)$ is included in $P(B)$" implies "$A$ is included in $B$".

Comment: Indeed $P(A)\subseteq P(B)\iff A\subseteq B$: If $A\subseteq B$, then every subset of $A$ is also a subset of $B$, and if $A\not\subseteq B$, then $A$ is a subset of $A$ that is not a subset of $B$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen. Thanks. Do you think there are counter-examples to the generalization : power sets of A and of B always have the same relations as the original sets A and B?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very natural relation to consider would be that of the cardinality of the sets. We certainly have that $|A| = |B|$ implies that $|P(A)| = |P(B)|$. You may ask whether or not the converse is true, so does $|P(A)| = |P(B)|$ imply $|A| = |B|$?

This turns out to be not necessarily true, it is in fact independent from ZFC. That means that there can be set-theoretic universes where $|P(A)| = |P(B)|$ implies $|A| = |B|$ (e.g. when GCH holds), but there can also be set-theoretic universes where this fails. So then there are $A$ and $B$ such that $|P(A)| = |P(B)|$ while $|A| \neq |B|$. See also this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/244873/661457.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take these sets as an example:
$$
\begin{align}
A &= \{1\} \\
B &= \{2\} \\
P(A) &= \{\emptyset, \{1\}\} \\
P(B) &= \{\emptyset, \{2\}\}
\end{align}
$$
A relation is in this context a function that takes two sets and gives true or false.

A simple counterexample relation is:
$$f(X, Y) = X \text{ contains a set}$$
Then we have:
$$
\begin{align}
f(A, B) &= \text{false} \\
f(P(A), P(B)) &= \text{true} \\
\end{align}
$$