# A free generating set $S$ of a free group $F$ has the smallest cardinality of the generating sets.

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

I'm reading Clara Löh's book "Geometric group theory, an introduction" and i'm going through the free groups section. She stated the following:

Let $F$ be a free group.

1. Let $S\subset F$ be a free generating set of $F$ and let $S' \subset F$ be a generating set. Then $|S'|\geq |S|$.

Here a free generating set is a set such that $F$ satisfies the Universal propertie of free groups.
She said that it could be derived from the universal propertie mapping $S$ to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. I tried this and i'm not sure if my argument it's correct.

The cardinality of maps from $S$ to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is $2^{|S|}=|P(S)|$ (where $P(S)$ is the power set of $S$), and as that cardinality is in bijection to the homomorphisms from $F$ to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ then we can restrict that homomorphism to $S'$, that set is a subset of the functions from $S'$ to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, so $2^{|S'|}\geq 2^{|S|}$ and that implies $|S'|\geq |S|$.

I'm fairly sure that an argument like that is what Clara Löh wanted from her hint, so if it's not correct i would love to see how to correct the argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This argument is not correct: $2^{|S'|}\geq 2^{|S|}$ does not necessarily imply $|S'|\geq |S|$ for infinite sets (in fact, this claim is independent of ZFC; see [Why continuum function isn't strictly increasing?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244870/why-continuum-function-isnt-strictly-increasing) for instance).  The argument does work if $S$ is countable, though.

To handle the uncountable case, note that the subgroup generated by $S'$ has cardinality at most $\max(\aleph_0,|S'|)$.  So $|S|\leq\max(\aleph_0,|S'|)$ which implies $|S|\leq |S'|$ if $S$ is uncountable.

Comment: Wouldn't the subgroup generated by $S'$ be $F$, and as there is an injection from $S$ to $F$, then $|S| \leq |F|$ so if $S$ is incountable then $F$ is incountable as well?

Comment: Right, that's the point.

Answer (score 3):

This cannot work, since it is consistent with ZFC that there are infinite cardinals $\lambda < \kappa$ with $2^{\lambda} = 2^{\kappa}$. See [MO/67473](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67473/).

Here is a reduction to the case of vector spaces. If $G$ is a group, then $V(G) := G/\langle \langle g^2 : g \in G \rangle \rangle$ is a commutative group, and in fact a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$. If $G$ a free group over some set $S$, it follows formally that $V(S)$ is a free $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector space over $S$, since the universal property is transported. If $G$ is generated by $S$, then $V(G)$ is generated by $S$ (as a vector space). (To the category-theoretic minded people: $V : \mathbf{Grp} \to \mathbf{Vect}_{\mathbb{F}_2}$ is left adjoint to the forgetful functor.)

So, if $G$ is free over $S$ and $S'$ is a generating set of $G$, then it follows that $V(S)$ has a basis $S$ and is generated by $S'$, hence $|S'| \geq |S|$.

Comment: PS: "free over S" does not mean that S is a subset of the given structure. It only requires a map from S. This also means that here you don't need to verify that S injects into V(G). We don't need injections, just maps, and they compose much better since here an epimorphism from G to V(G) is involved. So what I just want to say is that V(G) is free with respect to S --> G --> V(G).