# What is $n^{\aleph_0},n\in\mathbb N$

Tags: cardinals

Can I say that $$n^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0\log_2n}=2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$$

Comment: Last equality is only correct if you assume the Continuum hypothesis.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft by cantor's diagonalization isn't $2^{(\aleph_0=|\mathbb N|)}=(\aleph_1=|\mathbb R)$

Comment: No, the reals do not have cardinality $\aleph_1$ unless you assume the continuum hypothesis (this is precisely the continuum hypothesis)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft okay.

Comment: Also, you need $n\ge 2$ for this to hold

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen indeed

Comment: You may be interested in the [beth numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number). In this notation, $2^{\aleph_0}$ equals $\beth_1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no $\mathrm{log}_2$ in cardinal arithmetic, and you're assuming the continuum hypothesis to get from $2^{\aleph_0}$ to $\aleph_1$.

But note that:

> **Proposition.** For all infinite cardinals $\kappa$, we have $\kappa^\kappa = 2^\kappa.$

So if $n \leq \aleph_0$, then:

$$n^{\aleph_0} \leq \aleph_0^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}$$

Hence if $n$ is a cardinal number in the interval $[2,\aleph_0]$, then $n^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}$.

**Edit.** Regarding logarithms, note that since the natural numbers aren't closed under the usual logarithm, hence we certainly cannot extend it to the cardinal numbers. What we might try instead is to define a "best over-approximation" variant. Explicitly, given cardinals $\kappa \geq 0$ and $\nu \geq 2$, define that $\mathrm{log}_\nu(\kappa)$ is the least cardinal $\lambda$ such that $\nu^\lambda \geq \kappa$. For example, ZFC proves that $$\mathrm{log}_2(2^{\aleph_0}) = \aleph_0.$$

> *Side remark.* Order theoretically, all we've done is defined $\mathrm{log}_\nu\Box$ as the left-adjoint of $\nu^{\Box},$ which reads: $$\mathrm{log}_\nu (\kappa) \leq \lambda \iff \kappa \leq \nu^\lambda.$$

Now assuming the [injective continuum function hypothesis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376509/bijection-between-power-sets-of-sets-implies-bijection-between-sets/376540#376540), we have: $$\mathrm{log}_2(2^\kappa) = \kappa$$

Comment: I suppose n is finite and we can take log?

Comment: @ADG, I don't think so. Do you have an explicit definition of $\log$ you'd like to use?

Comment: no none, I think you are correct

Answer (score 1):

This is set power. Recall that for cardinals $A$ $B$, $A^B$ is the cardinal of $$\{f: B \to A\}.$$ How many applications $$f : \aleph_0 \to n$$ do you find for fixed $n$ ?

Comment: a number in base n-1? 0.abcde... 0<=a,b,c,d,e...<=n-1?

Comment: Yes, you can see it like that.

Comment: Then we would have a **decimal**equivalent of this number in $\mathbb R$ which would be in $[0,1]$ thus the cardinality must be $|\mathbb R|$?

Comment: You must just pay attention at one thing. In our context (let's say with $n=10$) $0,90000...$ and $0,8999999...$ are two different functions. However these are the same representation of $\frac{9}{10}$ in base $10$.