# Does $2^{\mathfrak m}=2^{\mathfrak n}$ imply $\mathfrak m=\mathfrak n$?

Tags: set-theory

Suppose $\mathfrak m$ and $\mathfrak n$ are infinite cardinals. Does $2^{\mathfrak m}=2^{\mathfrak n}$ imply $\mathfrak m=\mathfrak n$?

Comment: This is not a theorem of ZFC (unless ZFC happens to be inconsistent).

Comment: Do you bother searching the site? This has been asked at least twice before.

Comment: Also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420400/sets-question-without-zorns-lemma/ and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74477/does-2x-cong-2y-imply-x-cong-y-without-assuming-the-axiom-of-choice

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thanks for the links! I honestly tried to find it, but I worded it in a different way, so couldn't find any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is independent of ZFC. It is implied by GCH for example, but there exist models where (say) $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you possibly direct me to any source that states this fact?

Comment: Never mind, I got the links provided above.