# If two sets have the same cardinality, then so do their power sets. Converse can't be answered?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, intuition, visualization

<sub>The following is my rewrite of [this proof](http://ph.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100907061641AAE2Vfq) for the following assertion :</sub>

> For infinite sets $A, B$, $|A| = |B| \Longrightarrow  \require{cancel} \cancel{\Longleftarrow} |P(A)| = |P(B)|$.

$\bbox[2px,border:1px solid black]{\text{ Proof Strategem : }}$ We are given that $f :A \rightarrow B$, is a bijection. How do we construct a bijection between subsets of A and subsets of B? We need a rule whereby, if we take one subset of A, then we can use the rule to uniquely construct a unique subset of B. My intuition on this is to take all the elements of the subset of A, and map them under $f$ to elements of B, which will form a subset of B.

$\bbox[2px,border:1px solid black]{\text{ Proof : }}$  In mathematical notation, we define $g$ as: 
$g : P(A) \rightarrow P(B)$ by means of $\color{#009900}{g(S) = \{f(x) : x ∈ S\}} \; \forall S \subseteq A$.

$\bbox[2px,border:5px solid grey]{\text{ $g$ onto ? }}$ For all $T \subseteq B$, does there exist $S \subseteq A$ such that $\color{#009900}{g(S) = \{f(x) : x ∈ S\}} \; = T$?

Since $f^{-1}$ exists, define $S = \{f^{-1}(x) : x ∈ T\}.$ We must prove $\color{#009900}{\{f(x) : x ∈ S\}} = T$.

$\bbox[5px,border:1px solid grey]{T \subseteq g(S)}$ Take $y \in T \iff  f^{-1}(y) ∈ S \iff  \color{ #FF4F00}{f}[f^{-1}(y)] ∈ \color{ #FF4F00}g[S] \iff y \in g[S]. $

$\bbox[5px,border:1px solid grey]{{g(S)} \subseteq T}$ Take $y \in g(S)$ which means there exists $x \in S \ni f(\color{#C154C1}{x}) = y $.
Since $x \in S$ means there exists $t \in T \ni \color{#C154C1}{f^{-1}(t) = x}$, substitute this into the previous equation: $f(\color{#C154C1}{f^{-1}(t)}) = y \implies t = y $. Since $t \in T$, thus $y \in T$.

$\bbox[2px,border:5px solid grey]{\text{ $g$ 1-1 ? }}$
Suppose we have $G,H ⊆ A$ such that: $g(G) = g(H)$ which means $\{f(x) : x ∈ G\} = \{f(x) : x ∈ H\}$.

$\bbox[5px,border:1px solid grey]{\{f(x) : x ∈ G\}  \subseteq \{f(x) : x ∈ H\}}$ Take $g \in G \implies f(g) ∈ \quad g(G) = g(H) \quad \implies f(g) ∈ g(H)$.
Thus there exists a $h ∈ H$ such that  $f(g) = f(h)$
$\implies g = h$ because $f$ is a bijection.  Since $g ∈ G$, thus $g ∈ H$.

We can prove the other direction by the same argument, just with $G$ and $H$ swapped around.

$1.$ In the proof for $g$ onto, how would you (fore)know (ie: divine or presage) to define $S = \{f^{-1}(x) : x ∈ T\}$?

$2.$ Would someone please explain the step $f^{-1}(y) ∈ S \iff  \color{ #FF4F00}{f}[f^{-1}(y)] ∈ \color{ #FF4F00}g[S] $?

$3.$ Are there easier proofs? The result seems intuitive but the proof is complex.

$4.$ Are there any pictures?

$5.$ My course doesn't include $ZFC$. So what's the intuition why [the converse is false](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143463/53259)?

Comment: So for the last one you're really saying "I can't really understand a relatively simple and naive proof without resorting to visualizations [which are uberhard when it comes to power sets]. Please endow me with an informal reason of one of the major results in axiomatic set theory, which requires a deep philosophical understanding of provability and axiomatic set theory"?

Comment: @AsafKaragila that's kind of mean.

Comment: @fleablood: This comment wasn't posted "out of the blue". It's easy to look at it without the context of its time. But kudos to you.

Comment: Oh, my  Hadn't noticed the date.  My that was a while ago. So why did it show up as recent activity?  Sigh.  Now I feel I just wasted quite a bit of time painstakingly answering.  So... the was some history with this?

Comment: @fleablood: The question was edited about 20 minutes before you posted an answer.

Comment: Yeah.  Gotta look at dates.... sigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)  Well as card(A) = card(B) we know there is a 1-1 bijection (yes, I know that is redundant) where $a \leftrightarrow b = f(a)$.  So it's just plain common sense to look at $S = \{a\} \leftrightarrow g(S) = \{f(a)\}$.  If theres a bijective relation between the elements of A and B then it's just plain common sense to imagine there is a relationship between the subsets of A and those subsets of B with the corresponding equivalent elements, isn't it?

2) If $f^{-1}(y) = x \in S \implies y = f(f^{-1}(y)) \in  g(S) =\{f(x)|x \in S\}$

if $y = f(f^{-1}(y)) \in g(S) =\{f(x)|x \in S\}$ then $y = f(x)$ for some $x \in S$.  so $f^{-1}(y) = x \in S$.

3) Easier proofs? [How to proof card p(a) = card p(b)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1608505/how-to-proof-card-pa-card-pb/1608543#1608543) is the same proof but easier to read.  This is as basic a proof as it gets.  It is in short "there is a 1-1 correspondence between A and B so there will be a 1-1 correspondence between the subsets of A and the subsets of B containing the corresponding elements".  Can't get easier than that.

4) Pictures:

A = {1,2,3} B = {1x, 2x, 3x}. 1 <=> 1x, 2<=>2x, 3<=>3x.

P(A) = subsets of {1,2,3}.  P(B) = subsets of {1x,2x, 3x}

Subset S = {2,3} $\subset$ A <=> Subset g(S) = {2x, 3x}.  And so on.

5) Converse.  Given that |P(A)| = |P(B)| $\not \implies$ |A| = |B|.  Well we can't construct A, a superset, from a subset without the axiom of choice.  I think.  There is no counterexample.  It just can't be proven it can be done.

Comment: I'm struggling to find any reference for this (and I'm not a set theorist), but I believe I've heard that the converse is actually independent of ZFC. That is, there are models where $|P(A)|=|P(B)|$ does imply $A=B$ (e.g. ZFC+GCH) and models where it does not. Certainly, I don't think it's wise to keep your fifth point, because it doesn't address the complexity of what is in fact a deep issue.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised.  ZFC isn't my strong suit. ....  but wait can $2^v = 2^2$ with v and w being different cardinality? Or do |P(A)| not always equal 2^|A| for uncountable |A|?

Comment: The problem is the first - ZFC can't rule out $|2^v|=|2^w|$ might hold for $|v|\neq |w|$. I found a reference for it too with our [friends at MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/67473/equality-of-cardinality-of-power-set).

Answer (score 1):

The converse can not be answered in $ZF$. Let me explain: the general continuum hypothesis (GCH) states that if $\alpha$ is an infinite cardinal then there is not cardinal $\beta$ with 
$\alpha < \beta < 2^\alpha$. This hypothesis is independent of other axioms of set theory (you can not prove or disprove it). So if you accept it as another axiom then yes the converse of your problem it true (which is clear). On the other hand there are models of set theory, ZF, such that your problem fails to be true.

Comment: This really doesn't answer any part of the question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Dear Asaf, I do not agree, in fact I was trying to provide some answer to parts $5$ and $3$.

Comment: But the OP acknowledged that it cannot be proved. You only repeated that, without giving an informal or intuitive reason as to why this is the case.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Because it seems that OP (as it is said in 5)  is not familiar with ZFC. I just wanted to show a picture. On the other hand there is no harm in providing some potentially helpful answers.

Comment: "I just wanted to show a picture." I do not understand what picture you are showing here.