# Is strict cardinality ordering preserved by power sets?

Tags: set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Suppose that $\#A<\#B$. That is, $B$ has *strictly* greater cardinality than $A$.

> Is it necessarily true that $\#(2^A)<\#(2^B)$? In particular, is this question decidable in ZFC without the (generalized) continuum hypothesis?

[I know that $\#(2^A)=\#(2^B)\Longrightarrow\#A=\#B$ is *not* decidable in ZFC](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29366/do-sets-whose-power-sets-have-the-same-cardinality-have-the-same-cardinality), but this seems to be a different question (though I'm not 100% certain). It is also true (in ZFC) that $\#A<\#B$ implies $\#(2^A)\leq\#(2^B)$. The question is whether the “weak inequality” can be strengthened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the same question. Cardinals are always comparable (with AC) and $\#(2^A)=\#(2^B)\Longrightarrow\#A=\#B$ is equivalent to  $\#A\ne\#B\Longrightarrow\#(2^A)\ne\#(2^B)$.

Comment: I'm a little embarrassed for not having realized this earlier. Thank you.